# Space between components in React Native styling

Tags: reactjs, gridview, react-native, flexbox

[image]

I have 6 `View` components (shown in the picture) , I want to have space between all 6 `View` components.

My code:

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'column',flex:6}}>
            <View style={{flex:2,flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'red',flex:1}}>
                </View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'blue',flex:1}}>
                </View>
            </View>


            <View style={{flex:2,flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'white',flex:1}}>
                </View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'black',flex:1}}>
                </View>

            </View>

            <View style={{flex:2,flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'gray',flex:1}}>
                </View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'yellow',flex:1}}>
                </View>

            </View>


 </View>
```

Comment: have you tried to simply add a `margin: 10` to your inner View elements?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try to add padding to the element then and another blank view in each row, padding make space between each item

[image]

```
<View style={{
      flexDirection:'column',
      flex:1,
    }}>
        <View style={{flex:2,flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:'space-between',padding:10}}>
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'red',flex:2,padding:10}}>
            </View>
          <View style={{flex:0.1}}/>
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'blue',flex:2,padding:10}}>
            </View>
        </View>

        <View style={{flex:2,flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:'space-between',padding:10}}>
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'white',flex:2,padding:10}}>
            </View>
            <View style={{flex:0.1}}/>
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'black',flex:2,padding:10}}>
            </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:2,flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:'space-between',padding:10}}>
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'gray',flex:1,padding:10}}>
            </View>
            <View style={{flex:0.1}}/>
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'yellow',flex:1,padding:10}}>
            </View>
        </View>
```

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to do that with only `justifyContent` and no paddings or margins...

Answer (score 43):

As of React Native 0.71.0, [you can use the `gap` property](https://github.com/reactwg/react-native-releases/discussions/41). These child views will have a gap of 10 pixels between each row / column.

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'column', gap: 10 }}>
  <View />
  <View />
  <View />
  <View />
  <View />
  <View />
</View>
```

Comment: Amazing, I'll need to upgrade, I'm at 0.66 sadly

Comment: Tried upgrading but `0.71.0` doesn't exist yet for public

Comment: columnGap does not work in the flat list that renders columns > 2, does it works for you?

Answer (score 12):

You can simply add margins to the elements and it will work fine.
[image]

```js
<View style={{flexDirection:'column',flex:6}}>
  <View style={{flex:2,flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:'space-between', marginBottom: 10}}>
    <View style={{backgroundColor:'red',flex:1, marginRight: 5}}>
    </View>
    <View style={{backgroundColor:'blue',flex:1, marginLeft: 5}}>
    </View>
  </View>


  <View style={{flex:2,flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:'space-between', marginBottom: 10}}>
    <View style={{backgroundColor:'white',flex:1, marginRight: 5}}>
    </View>
    <View style={{backgroundColor:'black',flex:1, marginLeft: 5}}>
    </View>
  </View>

  <View style={{flex:2,flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:'space-between', marginBottom: 10}}>
    <View style={{backgroundColor:'gray',flex:1, marginRight: 5}}>
    </View>
    <View style={{backgroundColor:'yellow',flex:1, marginLeft: 5}}>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the `map` function to render your components, you can try the following code:

```
// Change to the number of columns in your grid
const numCols = 4;

// Change to the spacing for each item
const spacing = '1.25rem';

// Parent View
<View style={{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  }}
>
{// List of child views to render
contents.map((content, index) => (
    // add a margin of 'spacing' to the bottom of all cards
    // will supply a left-margin to all cards in between the gap,
    // everytime a card is NOT divisible numCols, add a margin to the left
    <View style={{
      marginBottom : spacing,
      marginLeft: index % numCols !== 0 ? spacing : 0 
    }}
    >
    <Card 
      key={index}
      content={content}
      />
    </View>
  ))
}
</View>
```

I found that using the following code snippet will create an effect similar to [gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap) in css grids.

[image]

Comment: can you alter it so that the marginBottom is also 0 when it is the last row?

Comment: Can you show the full code? It's not clear to me how you ensure it gets 4 columns unless you divide the container width by 4 and limit each Card to that width. Also your numCols says 4 but the graphic shows 3. I like your solution, but I don't think it's complete

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: As of `react-native 0.71.0` you can use the gap property directly in the styles Refer: https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/01/12/version-071#simplifying-layouts-with-flexbox-gap

Try this

```
const Component = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.child}></View>
      <View style={styles.child}></View>
    </View>
  );
};

// Gap you want to achieve
const gap = 8;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    paddingHorizontal: (gap / -2),
  },
  child: {
    marginHorizontal: gap / 2,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Give the following styling to the parent container (Block/View).

```
  justifyContent: 'space-around'
```

OR

```
  justifyContent: 'space-between'
```

Space-around will put space between all the elements/view/items and also add space to the borders. Same as all elements get the margin.
And the space-between will put the space between all items, without adding space to the borders
All this stuff is explained here beautifully. [Here is the link](https://medium.com/wix-engineering/the-full-react-native-layout-cheat-sheet-a4147802405c)

Comment: But this will justify the content to center. It would't work if you would want the items to be left aligned with trailing white space.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the solution, [among using `justify-content: 'space-between'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67984146/3151675), was to explicitly give width to the parent view (in my case, `width: '100%'`), otherwise, 'space-between' didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 solutions in this case

first, use margin/padding for make air between flex element

and the other way is set justifyContent to 'space-between' ||  'space-around'

but you must know about some information to use the best solution in a different case

1- (margin-padding)

in some case (more case), padding better margin

as you know, if we have a box ( means element ), you have two space,

first between content and border [ Inner space ]

second, space between the border and another foreign box element [ outer space ]

if you have an element and you want move element in your style you must use margin, because if you use padding for your element, inner space changed and in many cases, this approach creates some crash in your element, 
{{ if you want to use padding you must create one View and wrap all of your element and set the padding for a wrapper for you }}

and if you want to use space-between || space-around, you must know this,
space-between and space-around have one diff

in space-between, space produced between elements and not create space between your element with sides

and space-around set space with elements and with sides

Answer (score 1):

You can give the parent a negative margin in the same direction you use on the children.

```
const Comp: FC = () => {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.item}></View>
      <View style={styles.item}></View>
      <View style={styles.item}></View>
      <View style={styles.item}></View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    // Just for visual representation:
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#FF0000',
    height: 100,

    // Important styles:
    marginRight: 15,
    flexBasis: '40%',
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  container: {
    // Important styles:
    marginRight: -15,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
});

export default Comp;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put some vertical space, without flex, this is simple (just for temporary use)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
          {Array(30)
            .fill({ name: "product name" })
            .map((item, key, arr) => (
              <View
                key={key}
                style={{
                  height: 200,
                  paddingTop: 15,
                  backgroundColor: "skyblue",
                  ...(key % 2 !== 0
                    ? { paddingRight: 15, paddingLeft: 15 }
                    : { paddingLeft: 15 }),
                  flexBasis: "50%",
                }}
              >
                <View
                  style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    backgroundColor: variables?.BackgroundLight,
                  }}
                >
                  <Text style={styles && { ...styles?.text }}>{item.name}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            ))}
        </View>
```

> Try this out. You can better control it using array `map`

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve the gap between the childrens by wrapping this component

```js
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { normalize } from '../../utils/responsiveSizes';

const VerticalSpace = ({ children, gap = normalize(8), style }) => {
  if (!children) {
    return null;
  }

  if (children && !children?.length) {
    return children;
  }

  const getPaddingBottom = (index) => {
    if (children.length === index + 1) {
      return 0;
    }
    return gap;
  };

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, style]}>
      {children?.map((child, index) => (
        <View key={index} style={{ paddingBottom: getPaddingBottom(index) }}>
          {child}
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

VerticalSpace.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  gap: PropTypes.number,
  style: PropTypes.object,
};

export default VerticalSpace;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
});
```

And you can use the VerticalSpace component like this

```js
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { normalize } from '../../utils/responsiveSizes';

const App = ({ children, gap = normalize(8), style }) => {

  return (
    <VerticalSpace>
      <Children1/>
      <Children2/>
      <Children3/>
      ...
    </VerticalSpace>
  );
};


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

## For `FlatList` or `ScrollView`:

Pass it through `contentContainerStyle` instead of `style`.

```
<FlatList
  style={styles.listContainer}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.list}

  keyExtractor={({ id }) => id}
  data={[/* ... */]}
  renderItem={({ item: { name } }) => (
    <View style={styles.card}>
      <Text>{name}</Text>
    </View>
  )}
/>

// ...
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  listContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "blue",
  },
  list: {
    gap: 4,
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  card: {
    padding: 8,
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "green",
  },
});
```

[image: rendered screen]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

## Soltuon1:

if you are using `React native >= 0.71` version, you can use **gap**, **rowGap**, **columnGap** [<=Reference](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/1373a7057b9d66830868832a9684ad80ae5d9d45)

like this

```
<View 
style={{ flexDirection:'row', gap: 10 }}
>

OR

<View 
style={{ flexDirection:'row', rowGap: 10, columnGap: 10 }}
>
```

## Solution 2:

If you are using `React native < 0.71` then you can wrap your component within `View` and then you can pass padding into parent view by checking the loop index, like this

```
renderItem={({item, index}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{paddingRight:index%2===0?0:10}}>
      <YourComponent />
    </View>
  );
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        <View style={{flex:2,flexDirection:"row",flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'white',flex:1,marginHorizontal:5,marginVertical:10,}}>
            </View>
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'black',flex:1,marginHorizontal:5,marginVertical:10,}}>
            </View>

        </View>

        <View style={{flex:2,flexDirection:"row",flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'gray',flex:1,marginHorizontal:5,marginVertical:10,}}>
            </View>
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'yellow',flex:1,marginHorizontal:5,marginVertical:10,}}>
            </View>

        </View>
```

Comment: Give some explanation please.

Comment: you need to refer this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props

Answer (score -3):

You can add the following in your style:

```
attachcontainer{
   flexDirection:  'row',
   justifyContent: 'space-between'
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly with some explanation.