# Fill space between component in React-native

Tags: react-native, dropdownbox

i try to develop an app in React-native. I put in app's toolbar 1 home button, 1 dropdownbox component and 1 menu button like in following screenshot in portrait mode:
[image: Portrait mode]
but in landscape mode the dropdownlist component don't fill the around space:
[image: Landscape mode]

i 'd like dropdownbox fills the space around. How can i do it?

This is my App.js:

```
import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View, StatusBar, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import * as React from 'react';

import ToolBar from './components/ToolBar'


export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ToolBar />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop:StatusBar.currentHeight,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    width:'100%',
    height:'100%',
  },
 
});
```

and this is my ToolBar.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Picker, StyleSheet, StatusBar, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { SelectList } from 'react-native-dropdown-select-list';

var listWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width; //full width
var height = Dimensions.get('window').height; //full height

export default function ToolBar()  {

  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState("");

  const data = [
        {key:'1', value:'Mobiles'},
        {key:'2', value:'Appliances'},
        {key:'3', value:'Cameras'},
        {key:'4', value:'Computers'},
        {key:'5', value:'Vegetables'},
        {key:'6', value:'Diary Products'},
        {key:'7', value:'Drinks'},
  ];

 return (
    <View  style={styles.container}> 
      <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../assets/home.png')} />
      <SelectList  
        style={styles.dropdownlist}
        data={data} 
        setSelected={setSelected} 
      />
      <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../assets/menu.png')} />
   </View> 
    )
      
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex:1,
      flexDirection:'row',
      width:'100%',
      margin: 2,
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "space-between",
    
     },
   
    logo: {
      height: 48,
      width: 48,
      padding: 1, 
    },
    dropdownlist: {
      width:listWidth,
    },
   
})
```

Can you help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can add flex: 1 to your dropdownlist style. Like this:

```
dropdownlist: {
    flex: 1
}
```

And the width property is redundant after that. Also the flex: 1 property is not needed for the container, so remove that too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself following this question: [Space between components in react native styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45503294/space-between-components-in-react-native-styling)

in this way in my **ToolBar.js**:

```js
return (
    <View  style={{flexDirection:'row', flex:3, justifyContent: "space-between"}}> 
      <View style={{ padding: 2 }}><Image source={require('../assets/home.png')} /></View>
      <View style={{flex:1, padding: 2, width:'100%'}}>
        <SelectList  
          data={data} 
          setSelected={setSelected} 
        /></View>
      <View style={{ padding: 2}}><Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../assets/menu.png')} /></View>
   </View> 
    )
      
  }
```